# find_all with camelCase tag names with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an xml file with BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 that has tag names in camelCase and find_all doesn't seem to be able to find them. Example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
<hello>
    world
</hello>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")

for x in soup.find_all("hello"):
    print x

xml2 = """
<helloWorld>
    :-)
</helloWorld>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml2, "lxml")

for x in soup.find_all("helloWorld"):
    print x
```

The output I get is:

```
$ python soup_test.py
<hello>
    world
</hello>
```

What's the correct way to look up camel cased/uppercased tag names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any case-sensitive parsing using BeautifulSoup, you would want to parse in `"xml"` mode. The default mode (parsing HTML) doesn't care about case, since HTML doesn't care about case. In your case, instead of using `"lxml"` mode, switch it to `"xml"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml2 = """
<helloWorld>
    :-)
</helloWorld>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml2, "xml")

for x in soup.find_all("helloWorld"):
    print x
```